# Intellisense not working for remote VSCode window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am encountering this error where intellisense does not work for my python files in my ssh window (accessed with the remote development kit). I have uninstalled and reinstalled. My `settings.json` file on my remote workstation match my `settings.json` file on my laptop (where intellisense does work). I have tested to make sure that the correct python interpreter is selected on my ssh machine, and that this python interpreter launches and will run code.

My output window previously showed this error:

```
Error 2021-04-30 13:53:16: Failed to check if file needs to be fixed [EntryNotFound (FileSystemError): Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+172.16.214.73/home/jkang/.config/Code/User/settings.json' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+172.16.214.73/home/jkang/.config/Code/User/settings.json')
    at _handleError (/home/jkang/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d/out/vs/server/remoteExtensionHostProcess.js:86:154942)
    at async y.readText (/home/jkang/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/out/client/extension.js:9:339523)
    at async p.doesFileNeedToBeFixed (/home/jkang/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/out/client/extension.js:59:577126)
    at async /home/jkang/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/out/client/extension.js:59:576253
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async p.getFilesToBeFixed (/home/jkang/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/out/client/extension.js:59:576199)
    at async p.updateTestSettings (/home/jkang/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190/out/client/extension.js:59:575826)] {
  code: 'FileNotFound'
}
```

I created this file `home/jkang/.config/Code/User/settings.json` with content `{}` in order to satisfy this error. It no longer shows.

Additionally, when I googled this problem some suggested that I run `python: build workplace symbols`. However, I am not able to and I get the error

```
Command 'Python: Build Workspace Symbols' resulted in an error (command 'python.buildWorkspaceSymbols' not found)
```

Can anyone help me? This is very frustrating.

Comment: For using remote and configuration related files in VS Code, please refer to this document:[Remote Development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). In addition, it is recommended that you also try to use "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)".